# Cloud Run warning log: Container called exit(3)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Cloud Run issued 'warning' log `Container called exit(3)` with no other errors messages neither from the CloudRun instance nor from the script that was calling the instance.
Metrics show normal CPU and memory utilization. No such logs reported before and there are a few container instances are active simultaneously. I assume only one of those issued the warning.

Is it something I need to dig into or is it something that may happen from time to time?

Comment: When does this event happen? Do you use a framework that handle the sigterm/sigkill?

Comment: Not sure about when.
I'm not using frameworks for sigterm/sigkill, but I'm suppressing docker's output with `--capture-output --error-logfile '../gunicorn.log' --log-level 'warning'` to avoid excessive logs

Comment: Can you share how do you build your container? (i.e. your Dockerfile)

Comment: it's pretty basic

    FROM python:3.8
    ...
    
    RUN pip install Flask gunicorn prophet
    ...
    CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 9 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app --capture-output --error-logfile '../gunicorn.log' --log-level 'warning'

Comment: Let me try and run it a few times more if that occurs again. Thanks for looking into this!